# Pushing the below section with the height of the text

Tags: html, css

I have carousel with image. Above the image I've placed one div with text.

Now I want to place second div, next to the first one but a bit lower and to push the bellow section down and show the text.

What is happening is that the second div with the text is visible only while the text is above the carousel. Once the text is extended bellow it is hidden behind the bellow section.

Here is the demo of what I have so far

```css
.mask-what-we-do {
  width: 444px;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: #1b1a1a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
}

.mask-follow-text {
  width: 633px;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 81px;
  left: 500px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 340px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="head-image" class="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/madgexdotcom-assets/transforms/pageheaders/2490/header-careers-2_73f47f2168e54879fea667b73c67519e.jpg" alt="Image">
      <div class="mask-what-we-do">
        <hr style="width: 375px;margin-top: 50px;border-top: 1px solid #fff;">
        <p style="height: 24px;color: #ffffff;padding:35px; font-weight: 900;margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;"><i>Lorem Ipsum</i></p>
      </div>
      <div class="mask-follow-text">
        <p style="height: 24px;color: #ffffff;padding:35px;margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>
        <p style="height: 24px;color: #000;padding:35px;margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>

        <p style="height: 24px;color: #000;padding:35px; margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>

        <p style="height: 24px;color: #000;padding:35px;margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>

        <p style="height: 24px;color: #000;padding:35px;margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>

        <p style="height: 24px;color: #000;padding:35px;margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="partners-title" style="text-align:center;">Lorem</h2>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

The second white div above the image with the `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,` text doesn't push the `<section>` bellow and it is not visible.

Here is also [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv3pa8ug/1) of it.

UPDATE: adding image of what it need to be
[image]

Comment: you want them all to fit on the image ? or the second section is out

Comment: The second section (the white box) should be a bit lower, not fit as the black div.

Comment: it should go out of the height 340px and should not be on the image? because  if you increase the height it will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```css
.mask-what-we-do {
  background-color: #1b1a1a;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 50px;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.mask-follow-text {
  width: 633px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/-1;
}

.item-wrap {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px auto;
}

.item-wrap img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  grid-column: 1/ -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.team {
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="head-image" class="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="item-wrap">
        <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/madgexdotcom-assets/transforms/pageheaders/2490/header-careers-2_73f47f2168e54879fea667b73c67519e.jpg" alt="Image">
        <div class="mask-what-we-do">
          <hr style="margin-top: 50px;border-top: 1px solid #fff;">
          <p style="height: 24px;color: #ffffff;padding:35px; font-weight: 900;margin-top: -35px;font-size: 24px;"><i>Lorem Ipsum</i></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mask-follow-text">
          <p style="padding:3px;font-size: 24px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>
          <p style="padding:3px;font-size: 24px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>
          <p style="padding:3px;font-size: 24px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>
          <p style="padding:3px;font-size: 24px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In arcu ante, elementum. </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="partners-title" style="text-align:center;">Lorem</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            </p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't need the scroll there. I need this to be all visible

Comment: @Jordan, I have updated the above code. Removed all the heights and added a min-height property. Can you check this?

Comment: thanks but is not what I aim. The second div (the white one) should be lower than the black one and should push the content bellow (the second section)

Comment: I've updated my question with image of how should be

Comment: so `div 2` should push the `second section` and should look like on the image

Comment: @Jordan, again edited the above code. I think this will help you. Could you please check the above code?